# React JS: Check for comma within input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state object with a nested array of objects called "axisLabels".

If the user is to enter anything into the input, I want to check if there is a comma (comma separated) within event.target.value of the input to update the second object within the array.

How is this possible?

My current function code updates both.

State obj:

```
selectedTemplateData: {
   axisLabels: ['Option 1', 'Option 2']
}
```

function to update array:

```
axisChange(event) {
    event.persist();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedTemplateData: {
            ...prevState.selectedTemplateData,
            Axislables: [event.target.value, event.target.value]
        }
    }))

}
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text"  onChange={(event) => this.axisChange(event)} />
```

Comment: Do you want to check comma in event.target.value ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have explained that - will edit.

Comment: If you want to check comma in event.target.value you can use `if (event.target.value.indexOf(',') > -1) { event.target.value.split(',') }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would certainly work:

```
axisChange(event) {
    event.persist();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedTemplateData: {
            ...prevState.selectedTemplateData,
            Axislables: [...event.target.value.split(',')]
        }
    }))
}
```

If there is no comma, the value will be preserved.  If there is a comma, you can split the values and spread them into the new array.

Comment: Perfect and very nice elegant solution! Will mark correct when the timer allows.

Comment: You might want to check if `event.target.value` has a value (is not empty `''`).  This will happily add `""`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-into-an-array-in-javascript.php#targetText=Answer%3A%20Use%20the%20split(),to%20an%20array%20of%20characters.) you'll find other examples, but a simple way to do it is the following:

```
axisChange(event) {
    event.persist();
    const e = event && event.target && event.target.value;
    const values = e && e.split(',').length > 1
      ? e.split(',')
      : e;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedTemplateData: {
            ...prevState.selectedTemplateData,
            Axislables: [ values[0], values[1], values[n] ]
        }
    }))
}
```